# Specifying and allowing reordering of ingredients stored as rows in database

Tags: database, sorting, database-design, database-schema

I have an `Ingredient` table and a `Food` table, and want to link them up using an `IngredientToFood` table. I also want to be able to specify `Order` as this is very important to nutritional information. My `IngredientToFood` table currently has the columns `IngredientId`, `FoodId`, and `Order`, with a composite PK on the two ID's and 2 FK referencing each of the respective ID's. What I would like to know is the best-practice way to implement ordering the ingredients. I have seen the following solutions proposed here and elsewhere, and am wondering which is the best solution for my use-case.

1. Use the `Order` column to specify a numeric order, leaving lots of separation between (100, 200, 300, etc).
2. Use two columns, a `beforeIngredient` and `afterIngredient` in this case.
3. Use a trigger to renumber the existing `Order` values before an insert or delete (what do you do in the case of an update?)

I am not looking for the most elegant solution ever, but rather just one that makes sense for the application of ordering ingredients. I am assuming that I will probably inserting/deleting ingredients far more often than reordering existing ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use the Order column to specify a numeric order, leaving lots of separation between (100, 200, 300, etc).

This is the right idea, but you mentioned the importance of nutritional information.

You might want to also create a Nutrition table that lists the different nutrients you want to keep track of.  You would assign each nutrient a number, like 100, 200, 300, etc. where the lower numbers are the more important nutrients.

This nutrient number would be the order number in the Order table.

The advantage of having a Nutrition table over arbitrary Order numbers is that you can query the nutrients across your recipes.

Comment: Thanks, Gilbert... I actually invoked nutrition just to mean that the order of ingredients was _really_ significant in this application, not to actually go into the nutritional info of those ingredients... Should I combine the first approach with a Trigger in case I really use up all that space, or just deal with it when I get there?

Comment: @jshin47: I don't understand your question.